# Displaying multiple stacked layers in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, layouts, arcscene

I am looking for a way using Layout View in ArcMap 10.3 to display multiple layers in this manner:

[image]

I would call this a "map stack", yet I couldn't find a way to do this or how the displaying method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Layout View of ArcMap only displays a planimetric view.

For the view that you seek you could investigate the ArcScene application of ArcGIS 3D Analyst.